# Erro Estranho ao somar

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho 2 campos input e preciso somar o valor do conteudo deles ao digitar, mas eu reparei que quando eu digito o primeiro valor no primeiro input aparece `NaN` somente quando eu digito algo no segundo input, ele começa somar, então se eu tiver 5 inputs, eu teria que sigitar em todos para ter uma soma.

Eu quero que vá somar a medida que eu eu vou inserido os valores no input, sem precisar preencher todos, se eu preencher alguns já faz a soma,

Meu Código:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function somar()
{
 var campo_1 = document.getElementById("campo_1").value;
 var campo_2 = document.getElementById("campo_2").value;
    var campo_3 = document.getElementById("campo_3").value;
    var campo_4 = document.getElementById("campo_4").value;
    var campo_5 = document.getElementById("campo_5").value;

 var somar = parseInt(campo_1) + parseInt(campo_2) + parseInt(campo_3) + parseInt(campo_4) + parseInt(campo_5);

 console.log(somar);

}
</script>
<body>
<input id="campo_1" onkeydown="somar();" type="text"></input>
<input id="campo_2" onkeydown="somar();" type="text"></input>
<input id="campo_3" onkeydown="somar();" type="text"></input>
<input id="campo_4" onkeydown="somar();" type="text"></input>
<input id="campo_5" onkeydown="somar();" type="text"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso deve funcionar:

```
function somar()
{
    var campo_1 = document.getElementById("campo_1").value || 0;
    var campo_2 = document.getElementById("campo_2").value || 0;
    var campo_3 = document.getElementById("campo_3").value || 0;
    var campo_4 = document.getElementById("campo_4").value || 0;
    var campo_5 = document.getElementById("campo_5").value || 0;

    var somar = parseInt(campo_1) + parseInt(campo_2) + parseInt(campo_3) + parseInt(campo_4) + parseInt(campo_5);

    console.log(somar);

}
```

Comment: É isso que eu estava procurando, Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

vê se você consegue adaptar essa função para o que você quer.

```
    function somar()
    {
    total = 0; //variavel começa zerada
//funcao each que varre todos os elementos do tipo que voce quer
    $("input").each(function( index ) { 
        if ($(this).value != null) //se o valor for diferente de nulo
        {
        total += $(this).value; //adiciona valor à total
        }
console.log(total);
    });
```

Comment: Mas o valor não pode aparecer no campo, tem que ficar em branco, como eu faço amigo ?

Comment: alterei o codigo, ve agora

Comment: Esse if não é muito prático, pois eu tenho mais de 200 campos na tela, rsss. Não teria um jeito mais simples ?

Comment: alterei novamente, tente usar o exemplo acima pro que voce quer.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica.